# Can i see the collider of the CharacterController in the Unity editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an empty GameObject, and in there 2 cubes to represent a very simple character body with a head (both cubes have their box collider still on them).

On the (parent) empty GameObject i have added a CharacterController and a script to move it around.

Can i see the collider that the CharacterController is using in the editor (so i can resize it correctly to the size of my character)?

I am assuming here that (and this may very well be incorrect):

- CharacterController always uses its own capsule as a collider
- the box colliders of my cubes are irrelevant and may as well be removed

Comment: If you select one object with a collider you should see all colliders as a green mesh, but be sure that you have not compressed the component in the editor by hitting the little arrow.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. the actual CharacterController component has to be expanded in the inspector

Comment: Of you want to see it also without having the empty object selected have a look at [Gizmos.DrawWireMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawWireMesh.html) but combined with [OnDrawGizmos](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html) (instead of `OnDrawGizmosSelected` as used in the first example)